# Why is my half-wave rectifier output in mV when the input is AC 10Hz 100V?

Tags: ltspice, rectifier

[image]

I have made this circuit a handful of times in real life and it is giving me a positive cycle waveform.

Why is it not working now?

The input is taken from the IP Test point and ground and output is taken across output load resistor and ground.

The second image is the reference transformer with IP p-p 20V and OP p-p 60V.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at "Transformer_OP" - I think your problem is your transformer model.  Or maybe R1.

Comment: What is the turn ratio of the transformer? I think that has to do something with output.

Comment: Ok so @JRE is right I checked with a reference model I made for the transformer. There is something wrong but what it is exactly the same as the last one down to R1?

Comment: It is a 1:3 transformer @SOUHARDHYAPAUL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fault is not the series resistance, it's the values of the "transformer". Sure, you could show that the circuit works by changing the resistance but, as hinted by [Bruce Abbott](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536178/why-is-my-half-wave-rectifier-output-in-mv-when-the-input-is-ac-10hz-100v#comment1386793_536183), if you replace those μH with something more palpable, like 1 H, you can safely use a series resistance of 1k and get the desired waveform. In fact, if the transformer is a low power one, you can expect tens of Henry. This goes hand in hand with OP's words:

> I have made this circuit a handful of times in real life and it is giving me a positive cycle waveform.

and with OP's second picture, where the values are in H, rather than μH (even if a little exaggerated, maybe), a picture that shows inconsistency between tests.

[image: proof]

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @JRE, I simulated it with a different series resistance.

[image: Simulation 0.025R]
The series resistance limits the voltage, as the resistance of the coil is very small. So you made a voltage divider, where only a small part of the voltage sits across the coil.

Comment: OMG such a stupid mistake I made. Basics man!! Thank You.

Comment: And the magnetizing current is... 2.7 thousand amps!

Comment: True, but that is a seperate issue, as I just showed the "faulty" component was the value of R1. Rectifiers are not my main forte.